# How to write to PhysicalDrive?

Tags: drive, createfile, writefile

I am trying to write to a PhysicalDrive, e.g. "PhysicalDrive*N*", with no luck.  The drive is a USB thumb drive (4GB).

**What I tried:**

1. Opened device handle using h=CreateFile(name,...) with flags GENERIC_READ & WRITE, FILE_SHARE_READ & WRITE, OPEN_EXISTING.
2. WriteFile(h,buffer,count,&nwritten,NULL)
   It always fails after the *first 32KB are successfully written*, with ACCESS DENIED error.
3. Tried locking with ioctl FSCTL_LOCK_VOLUME (no difference)
4. Tried dismounting (ioctl FSCTL_DISMOUNT_VOLUME) (failed)
5. Tried FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING (no difference)
6. Always Run As Administrator
7. UAC is off
8. *ReadFile* always works just fine

**What am I missing?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a System Repair from the Windows 10 install DVD and everything appears to work just fine now. Go figure.